# What are the possible 'entry-types' for PROC CATALOG?

Tags: sas

The [documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/70377/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p19zn75uke0r03n1qt78tnochdy4.htm#n1x122q5le52x7n1pgfcwdm4po1e) is circular and appears incomplete on this topic.  The documentation basically says 'specify an entry type by placing an entry type after the equal sign.' Duh.  But *what entry types are there?*

Looking at the `"ENTRYTYPE= Option"` section links me back to the "Specifying an Entry Type".  Within the various statement syntax pages, I see possible entry types like 'program' and 'log'.  But surely there's a list somewhere that gives all the possible entry types.  You would think it would be contained within the `PROC CATALOG` documentation, but I can't find it.  All my Google searches bring me back to the `PROC CATALOG` documentation.  Is there a list of valid entry types or do I have to guess?

Comment: When documentation fails, I would search lexjansen.com for user group papers. This one seems useful, but a quick read didn't give en exhaustive list. http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi29/051-29.pdf. I haven't used catalogs to store much myself (other than what sas puts there for you, i.e. compiled macros, formats, compiled AF/SCL, etc)

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure there is a fixed list. You could try looking at what values are being used in the SASHELP catalogs.

```
proc sql;
  create table objtype as
    select objtype,count(*) as nobs
    from dictionary.catalogs
    where libname='SASHELP'
    group by 1
    order by 1
  ;
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Tom / @Lorem Ipsum, I was also in need of this list today.  Here is the dump from my session using the dictionary.catalogs query:

```
AMETHOD 
ASSIST 
CBT 
CLASS 
CLASSPKG 
DATAFORM 
DEV 
DEVMAP 
DICTNARY 
EDPARMS 
EIS 
ENGINE 
FILEFMT 
FOLDER 
FONT 
FONTLIST 
FORM 
FORMAT 
FORMATC 
FORMULA 
FRAME 
GRSEG 
HELP 
IMAGE 
IMOD 
INFMT 
INFMTC 
INTRFACE 
INVEST 
KEYMAP 
KEYS 
LAYOUT 
LIST 
MACRO 
MENU 
PCL 
PMENU 
PROGRAM 
PSL 
RANGE 
RESOURCE 
SCL 
SCREEN 
SLIST 
SOURCE 
SYSTEM 
TEMPLATE 
TOOLBOX 
TOOLSET 
TRANTAB 
WORKAREA
```